# How to replicate GPA's Sign and Compress option on command line in Windows

Tags: windows, gnupg, pgp, gpg4win

As the title says, I need to replicate GPA's "Sign and Compress" option on the command line. I'm trying to automate some encryption of files for submission to a bank and the instructions they gave me are to use the Sign and Compress option in GPA. I've spent quite a bit of time reading through the documentation for GPG and I can't figure it out.
The closest I've gotten to it is

```
gpg --batch --passphrase *********** -a -se
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what bank is offering OpenPGP?

Comment: I'm implementing a program to generate and send NACHA files. All the banks I'm working with require pgp encryption.

Comment: Wasn't aware of that standard up to now, which is not surprising from an European point of view as there are totally other systems in use over here. Thank you for the background!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPA only wraps GnuPG itself, thus all operations are (somehow) possible using the bare `gpg` command line application.

I guess you're not after sign and *compress*, but sign and *encrypt*. Compression is added automatically before encrypting clear text messages. Compression could be enforced by adding an `--compression-algorithm zip` parameter (the only algorithm that *must* be understood by all OpenPGP implementations).

Regarding *sign and encrypt*, you will have to define the recipient and use both the `--encrypt` and `--sign` commands, or their respective short forms `-e` and `-s`. In the end, all you missed is the recipient:

```
gpg --recipient [uid/key-id] --sign --encrypt
```

For automating the encryption and passing a passphrase, you already found the required options. `-a` or `--ascii` adds ascii armoring, which usually is not required but might prevent some transmission issues sometimes, but enlarges the file a little bit.

Comment: Where would I find the recipient then? In GPA and Kleopatra it just shows it as Our Company Name /Companyemail@domain.com. I tried that, b it  shows it as an invalid recipient. Which makes sense.

Comment: You should be able to either use their mail address, or lookup their key and use the key's key ID (which should be presented somewhere near it). For automated processes, better directly use the recipient's full fingerprint. And actually, you should be able to request the fingerprint from the recipient, and if he cares he will tell you in some secure way (so not an unsigned, untrusted e-mail, maybe a letter or in person).

Comment: Alright, thanks. I think I have the key already, I'll take a look in the morning.

Comment: I actually ended up needing the -u option and -s. Now I just need to figure out how to use -a and still have it output a .gpg.

Comment: By deafult GnuPG prints to stdout. If you want an ascii-armored file with name .gpg, either use a pipe (`gpg ... >file.gpg`) or the `-o` option. By the way, `man gpg` explains all those options, although being rather long.

Answer (score 0):

Why not install [Gpg4win](http://gpg4win.org/download.html)?

It includes [The GNU Privacy Assistant (GPA)](https://www.gnupg.org/related_software/gpa/index.html) .

Then you can use the exact instructions from the bank.

Comment: I have that installed. From what I've found, you can't use GPA from the command line. That's my problem. I need to be able to automate it.